# Can't install Ubuntu -- "0 MB of disk space left"

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, 13.04, 13.10

Initially I had Windows 7 and I hated it, so I borrowed a drive and got Ubuntu 13.04. Later I heard about the release of 13.10 "Saucy Salamander" Alpha so I got that too.

After a week, I got bored and installed Fedora. It crashed soon after. So I borrowed a drive again and got Ubuntu. After a month, I had only 3GB left of my 60GB harddrive. Then I got [MeeGo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MeeGo) and found out that I can't get Wifi, so I borrowed a drive again and tried to install Ubuntu.

As usual, I pressed <kbd>F12</kbd> and it allowed me to choose the drive. Then it booted up like normal and then I was asked to try or install Ubuntu. I clicked install Ubuntu. Then I had to choose whether to replace MeeGo with Ubuntu or something else. I replaced MeeGo. It said:

> 0 MB of disk space left

It stopped in the middle of installation and now I'm stuck with no OS. When I try to install Ubuntu, I get the same '0 MB of disk space left' message and it stops in the middle of the download.

How can I fix this issue and install Ubuntu on my Lenovo ThinkPad x201?  Do I need to do something to change the partitioning?

Comment: Perhaps you can describe what options you see during the installation when it asks you how to install ubuntu.  Choosing "Erase" will do just that - it will erase everything on the disk including all the O/S's you have installed.  Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Just a word of advise: Please try to add the actual question into the headline, if possible. "ubuntu does'nt work" is not very descriptive. And try to keep your description of the problem as short and to-the-point as possible. Add what you've done, where it went wrong and any information you think will be useful to know, when helping you solve the problem. Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The no splace left suggests a partitioning isue.  It is possible that the meego install or some of the previous Distro installs have partitioned the drive into small segments.
Solution

1. examine the disk structure....use Ubuntu in LiveCD mode and
   examine the drive.  Use gParted. You may have partitions related to
   the old OS and even Winodws recovery partitions there.
2. Plan your objectives...replace everything and start afresh? vs  try and
   recover old OS?.
3. I would explore the partitions, back up anything useful and then
   take a deep breath and reformat the drive into two
   partitions and 15GB for the /  and the rest for /home ...wiping ALL data
4. Install as before

Comment: thanks, and im trying to install ubuntu afresh. try Ubuntu  option makes the computer freeze.